# Executing bash file with Error bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: bash

I am very new to bash and try writing the first script named `hello_world` in the path of `/Users/me/Study/Linux` with the content written by vim:

```
#! bin/bash
echo Hello World
```

However, the error occurs when executed:

```
-bash: /Users/me/Study/Linux/hello_world: bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I have read many questions on the issue but still feel totally lost. :( I'll be very thankful for your help.

Comment: try `#! /bin/bash` for the first line

Comment: @TedWrigley Thx, that works; but why?

Comment: The shebang (#!) takes a path to an executable, and in Unix/linux, paths have to begin with a slash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first line of your bash script must look like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
```

This is called a "shebang line" because the first two characters `#!` are a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). The shebang line tells the computer which executable program should be used to interpret the rest of the script. In this case you're writing a bash script, but you could just as easily be writing a script for python or awk, and you need to tell the system which interpreter to use based on what language the script is written in.

The reason that your shebang line `#! bin/bash` doesn't work is because you haven't provided a valid path (typically, an [absolute path](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/absolute-path-vs-relative-path-linuxunix/)) to the interpreter. If you omit the initial slash `/` then the shell looks for `bin` in the current working directory but doesn't find it.

Since you're just getting started learning bash, I suggest reading a book. This will save you from having to ask too many questions. [Learning the bash Shell, 3rd Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596009656.do) by Cameron Newham is quite good.

Comment: Note that the space after the `#!` is unimportant - `#!/bin/bash` and `#! /bin/bash` both work and `#!bin/bash` or `#! bin/bash` will only work if you `cd /` first (so bin is found).  From your [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)#History) *"Blanks after ! are OK"*